# How to close all the browser instances before a test execution in selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a method through which we can close all the previously launched browser windows, before we get started with a new test in selenium Web driver.

I am trying to close the already launched chrome browser windows by the below code, but this is not helping in closing the previous browser windows instead it is closing the current chrome driver instance created in the test.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<Path of chromedriver.exe>");
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
for(String eachWindowHandle:chromeDriver.getWindowHandles()){
            chromeDriver.switchTo().window(eachWindowHandle).close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

We are using like this

```
String processName = "chromedriver.exe";
if (isProcessRunning(processName))
{
    Prerequisites.killProcess(processName);
}
```

Functions used are implemented as below=>

**isProcessRunning**

```
public static boolean isProcessRunning(String serviceName) 
{
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if (line.contains(serviceName)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**killProcess**

```
public static void killProcess(String serviceName) 
{
    try
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + serviceName + " /T");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to close all the browsers before opening new browser to run your desired tests

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <browserinstance>.exe");
```

eg :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
```